# How do i list out all dependencies for a package in Centos/Rhel?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm, dependencies

I am trying to install below tools on a system where i don't have internet connection.

- nodejs with npm
- jdk8
- firefox
- scripty

In order to get all the dependencies & packages, i logon to a system where i have internet connection and i use `yum install -downloadonly <package-name>`

I expected that this lists out all packages but no, when i try to install the packages in the system with no internet i get so many dependency failures. For example check below where i tried to install Firefox

Below are the dependency/package list i got from "downloadonly"

```
nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64.rpm
nss-devel-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64.rpm
nss-sysinit-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64.rpm
nss-tools-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64.rpm

rpm -Uvh nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64.rpm
warning: nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libnssutil3.so(NSSUTIL_3.21)(64bit) is needed by nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
    libnssutil3.so(NSSUTIL_3.24)(64bit) is needed by nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
    nspr >= 4.13.1 is needed by nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
    nss-pem(x86-64) is needed by nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
    nss-softokn(x86-64) >= 3.28.3-4 is needed by nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
    nss-util >= 3.28.4-2 is needed by nss-3.28.4-15.el7_4.x86_64
    nss = 3.19.1-18.el7 is needed by (installed) nss-sysinit-3.19.1-18.el7.x86_64
    nss(x86-64) = 3.19.1-18.el7 is needed by (installed) nss-tools-3.19.1-18.el7.x86_64
```

Two questions:

1. How do i list out all the dependencies for a tool ?
2. Even if i get the complete list then How do i know what to install first?

Answer (score 9):

Add 1. The command `# yum deplist [package-name]` will list all dependencies. See https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum ... or use `$ man yum` , if available.

Add 2. Say you are using the default install command ( like **yum** does ) : I.e. `rpm -Uvh [package] [package] [package] [package] [package] [package]` : "rpm" is smart : Installs in the right order, no matter how you ordered the packages.

Comment: is it possible to download all the dependencies that are listed out using "deplist". For example, for each tool i get lot of dependencies. It's not possible to get all

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean : »» is it possible to download all the dependencies that are listed out using "deplist" «« .... Download all: Yes, I guess so. ... "not possible to get all": Why not ?

Comment: Ok let me re-phrase, When i use #yum --downloadonly [package-name] it gives me only 4 packages. And when i check the dependency list using #yum deplist [package-name] it gives me more than 20 dependencies just for Firefox itself. So how do i get remaining packages ?
Do i need to download them manually and install ? I did the same and it's working but that's a lot of manual work

Comment: It *is* a lot of manual work ! The example "Firefox": Not all packages are required. Some never or rarely get updates. Or are already updated by other package installs. CentOS 7 : These are usually required at a firefox update : `nss.i686, nspr.i686, nss.x86_64, nspr.x86_64 nss-util.x86_64`